# How can I tell whether my potatoes are waxy vs. floury?

Tags: potatoes, ingredient-selection

Once in a while I get hold of a bunch of potatoes without any labeling and the least I want to know is whether they are waxy or floury. Is there a way to determine whether raw potatoes are waxy or floury?

Comment: I'll have to try @SZCZERZO-KŁY's method, as I wasn't aware of that one.  But "new potatoes" (small, young ones) tend to behave like waxy potatoes, even if they're from what's otherwise a floury variety.  (I don't know if it's the skins holding it together, or something botanically that only happens when they're larger)

Answer (score 4):

Cut one in half and rub each halves against each other. If water shows up the potatoes will hold together after boiling.

If the halves stick to each other and the juice is more cloudy than clear then the potatoes are starchy and "floury".